# Exist-db: specify order of transformation?

Tags: exist-db

I have +100 files in my exist-DB instance. 
I have them transform using a function. (https://pastebin.com/7Q2g4TPM)

I need several things: 
I need them being transformed in order from 0 -> last number (will be 162). They are named 00001.xml, the tens begin with 00010.xml, the hundreds with 00100.xml (do you get, what I mean?) 
I tried adding one file a time (up to 15 files) and I tried adding batches of files. All files are in the directory edition, with the first file at the moment being 00029.xml, which you find hardcoded as starting point for my Carousel (Bootstrap). (https://pastebin.com/WNKAgihw this pastebin is where I want them to be displayed for now. The structure etc. will probably change a little, but the general idea is this.)

Most of the time it seems to work fine, HOWEVER, with file 36 I get the case that this is displayed not at the needed position but two elements later. Later on, following 38, there is 142 inserted, then several mid-hundreds and then it goes back to "intended" order. I did not check for all files, but I saw this quite some times ...

Another question I have is this one: 
Can I somehow get a

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active">File 1</li>
    <li data-target="#carouselIndicators" data-slide-to="1">File 2</li>
    <li data-target="#carouselIndicators" data-slide-to="2"> File 3</li>
</ol>
```

where the `data-slide-to=""` is 1,2,3, etc. without hardcoding it for every file? 
I guess the function (first pastebin) can serve as a starting point, but how to make the  numbers go up ?

I hope I am clear with these questions and that someone knows how to help :-)

best wishes and many thanks in advance, 
K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely need to use a `order by` clause in the FLWOR expression of your XQuery.